# Как называется строка внизу окна браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, браузер

Периодически, во время полноэкранного режима, я вижу данную строку, которая отвлекает пользователей от просмотра видео.
Она показывает разные запросы, которые происходят для статистики или подгрузки рекламы.
Я пытался загуглить эту проблему, но никак не могу найти как она называется, есть ли у нее api или закономерности появление (при некоторых запросах она появляется, а при некоторых нет)...
Можете подсказать с чего начать?

[image: Строка запросов]

Comment: Называется status panel. Но отключить её насколько я понял нельзя... могу ошибаться.

Comment: statuspanel средствами CSS или JS отключить невозможно. Но можно отключить через настройки браузера. В Firefox, например, его можно убрать редактируя файл настроек - userChrome.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это status panel , её отсутствие или наличие зависит только от браузера , появляется из-за html тега "button".